# mysql database automatic partitioning

Tags: mysql, database, performance, partitioning

I have a mysql database table that I want to partition by date, particularly by month & year. However, when new data is added for a new month, I don't want to need to manually update the database.

When I initially create my database, I have data in Nov 09, Dec 09, Jan 10, etc. Now when February starts, I'd like a Feb 10 partition automatically created. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best idea. Each time you alter partitions, you'll be basically rewriting the entire table. This may take quite a lot of time and resources.

Comment: @Mchl if you have a better idea, I'd be glad to hear it. You're right, it's pretty intensive (more then I'd like), but if it only runs once a month it's not too bad - especially when I need to be doing regular queries like 'select the 3rd day of last month'.

Comment: "Each time you alter partitions, you'll be basically rewriting the entire table": not at all true. Adding partitions or removing partitions is like creating/dropping a table. Essentially instant. Only modifying an existing partition *that already has data in it* is potentially slow. So if you create a new partition for next month before you insert data in it, that's very fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few solutions out there, if you want a total solution, check this [post out on kickingtyres](https://web.archive.org/web/20121028114942/http://kickingtyres.com/words/mysql/mysql-partition-management/).  It's a basic combination of a stored procedure handling the partition analysis and creation (with some logging!).

All you need to do is adjust it to your partition type  (the example uses a bigint partition) and schedule the procedure to run with the MySQL Event Scheduler.

Comment: I like the concept of the stored procedure for the partition creation.

Comment: kickingtyres link is broken.

Comment: Dead links aren't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you might like the enhanced partitioning functionality in 5.5:

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_55_partitioning.html

Comment: Would I need to setup a trigger each month to add a new partition for that month? Since I don't want to define all months/years ahead of time...

Comment: @Jeff - I don't believe so, nothing noted in that article anyway.  Those are great enhancements, but won't solve your current problem...one I faced when SQL Server added partitions at first as well, PITA for sure.

Comment: @Nick Craver. The article you posted had stored procedures for doing it. I guess I could use a monthly trigger (or cron job, details TBD) to add a new partition via the stored procedure. Thanks.

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 0):

I will do what the other done (post a link) [Quick Introdunction to MySQL Partitioning](http://www.slideshare.net/datacharmer/mysql-partitions-tutorial)

(look at page 50 for what you need - partition by date)
Edit: I reread your post more carefully - if you want to change partitions by month why don't you create a Mysql `event` that does that

Comment: I is a sugestion. But i think you will end up with an event an a stored procedure to do what you want.