# mysql database automatic partitioning

Tags: mysql, database, database-partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql database automatic partitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174112/mysql-database-automatic-partitioning)

This is an exact duplicate of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174112/mysql-database-automatic-partitioning). Unfortunately that question was only answered by people posting links to sites that no longer work, so I'm hoping someone can, I don't know, re-post the solution where I can find it?

Anyway, the question is, how do I automatically update mysql database partitions. For example, if I want to have 3 partitions, representing 'this month', 'last month', and 'further in the past', how would I do it?

I can see how to create the partitions, but when this month rolls over to the next, I need them to automatically change. For instance, if today is november 29, the three partitions should have the data from november, october, and dates further back. Then a day later on december 1st, I want the three partitions to be december, november, and further back.

I assume this is possible, as the other question did have an accepted answer, so how do I do it?

Comment: Not a 'possible' duplicate. This is a duplicate. As I mentioned in line 1 - I'm repeating the question because that one was not answered.